# how do I split a dataframe by row into chunks of n, apply a function and combine?

Tags: r, split, apply

I have a `data.frame` of 130,209 rows.

```
> head(dt)

              mLow1 mHigh1 mLow2 mHigh2 meanLow meanHigh        fc     mean
     A_00001  37.00  12.75 99.25  78.50  68.125   45.625 1.4931507  56.8750
     A_00002  31.00  21.50 84.75  53.00  57.875   37.250 1.5536913  47.5625
     A_00003  72.50  26.50 81.75  74.75  77.125   50.625 1.5234568  63.8750
```

I want to split the `data.frame` in 12, apply the `scale` function on the column `fc` and then combine it. There is no grouping variable here, else I'd have used `ddply`. Also, because 130,209 is not perfectly divisible by 12, the resulting `data.frames` will be unbalanced, i.e., 11 `data.frame`s will have 10,851 rows and the last one will have 10,848 rows, but that's fine.

So how do I split a `data.frame` by row into chunks of n (in this case 12), apply a function and then combine them together? Any help'd be much appreciated.

**Update**:
Using the two top solutions, I get different results:
Using @Ben Bolker's solution,

```
mLow1 mHigh1 mLow2 mHigh2          UID       gene_id meanLow meanHigh mean         fc
  1.5   3.25     1   1.25 MGLibB_00021 0610010K14Rik    1.25     2.25 1.75 -0.5231249
  1.5   3.25     1   1.25 MGLibA_00034 0610037L13Rik    1.25     2.25 1.75 -0.5231249
  1.5   3.25     1   1.25 MGLibB_00058 1100001G20Rik    1.25     2.25 1.75 -0.5231249
  1.5   3.25     1   1.25 MGLibA_00061 1110001A16Rik    1.25     2.25 1.75 -0.5231249
  1.5   3.25     1   1.25 MGLibA_00104 1110034G24Rik    1.25     2.25 1.75 -0.5231249
  1.5   3.25     1   1.25 MGLibA_00110 1110038F14Rik    1.25     2.25 1.75 -0.5231249
```

Using @MichaelChirico's answer:

```
mLow1 mHigh1 mLow2 mHigh2          UID       gene_id meanLow meanHigh mean        fc  fc_scaled
  1.5   3.25     1   1.25 MGLibB_00021 0610010K14Rik    1.25     2.25 1.75 0.5555556 -0.5089608
  1.5   3.25     1   1.25 MGLibA_00034 0610037L13Rik    1.25     2.25 1.75 0.5555556 -0.5089608
  1.5   3.25     1   1.25 MGLibB_00058 1100001G20Rik    1.25     2.25 1.75 0.5555556 -0.5089608
  1.5   3.25     1   1.25 MGLibA_00061 1110001A16Rik    1.25     2.25 1.75 0.5555556 -0.5089608
  1.5   3.25     1   1.25 MGLibA_00104 1110034G24Rik    1.25     2.25 1.75 0.5555556 -0.5089608
  1.5   3.25     1   1.25 MGLibA_00110 1110038F14Rik    1.25     2.25 1.75 0.5555556 -0.5089608
```

Comment: this number of row is not big. Why would you like to operate scale separately and combine results instead of directly scale the fc column??

Comment: I want to control the fc (fold change) for mean abundance (mean). The data is sorted by mean in my actual dataframe. I want to calculate zscore separately for separate chunks of mean abundances (really low, low...med...high...to very high)

Comment: Why not use `cut(1:nrow(dt), 12)` with split?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ggplot2` has a `cut_number()` convenience function that will do this for you.  If you don't want the overhead of loading that package, you can look at `ggplot2:::breaks` for the necessary logic.

Reproducible example stolen from @MichaelChirico:

```
set.seed(100)
KK<-130209L; nn<-12L
library("dplyr")
dt <- data.frame(mLow1=rnorm(KK),mHigh1=rnorm(KK),
               mLow2=rnorm(KK),mHigh2=rnorm(KK),
               meanLow=rnorm(KK),meanHigh=rnorm(KK),
               fc=rnorm(KK),mean=rnorm(KK)) %>% arrange(mean)
```

With apologies to those who don't like pipes:

```
library("ggplot2")  ## for cut_number()
dt %>% mutate(grp=cut_number(mean,12)) %>%
       group_by(grp) %>%
       mutate(fc=c(scale(fc))) %>%
       ungroup() %>%        
       select(-grp) %>%     ## drop grouping variable
       as.data.frame -> dt2 ## convert back to data frame, assign result
```

It turns out that the `c()` around `scale()` is necessary -- otherwise the `fc` variable ends up with some attributes that confuse `tail()` ...

The same logic should apply to using `plyr`, or base R split-apply-combine, as well (the key is using `cut_number()` to define the grouping variable).

Comment: I am sorry I don't quite use dplyr. I am getting an object of class `[1] "grouped_df" "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"`. How do I get it in data.frame? I can't view the data and can't do `as.data.frame` on it.

Comment: I used  %>% as.data.frame() at the end and it works. Thanks.

Comment: Actually I can't even access the bottom of the the data. When I use tail() it gives me `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  dims [product 10899] do not match the length of object [130209]
`

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure the structure of `dt` matters that much (if you are not using any of its internal values to do the splitting). Does this help?

```
 spl.dt <- split( dt , cut(1:nrow(dt), 12) )

 lapply( spl.dt, my_fun)
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried your solution, changed `lapply` to `ldply` to return a data.frame & it works.

Answer (score 2):

With `data.table`, you can do:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt)[,scale(fc),by=rep(1:nn,each=ceiling(KK/nn),length.out=KK)]
```

Here, `KK` is 130,209 and `nn` is 12. Reproducible data:

```
set.seed(100)
KK<-130209L; nn<-12L
dt<-data.frame(mLow1=rnorm(KK),mHigh1=rnorm(KK),
               mLow2=rnorm(KK),mHigh2=rnorm(KK),
               meanLow=rnorm(KK),meanHigh=rnorm(KK),
               fc=rnorm(KK),mean=rnorm(KK))
```

So no need to split the data and recombine.

If you'd like to add this to the data frame instead of just extract it, you can use the `:=` operator to assign by reference:

```
setDT(dt)[,fc_scaled:=scale(fc)...]
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure this divides the data in the right way; I think you need something like `rep(1:nn,each=ceiling(KK/nn),length.out=KK)` ?

Comment: @MichaelChirico I am getting different results using your solution and the one above.

Comment: Still a different result using both solutions. See update.

Comment: Your and @BondedDust's results are pretty much the same, there is a slight difference in cutting (the 4th chunk is smaller than the rest of the chunks in his case, your 12th chunk is smaller than the rest). But that doesn't matter. Thanks!

Comment: @KomalRathi OK, I was hoping it would be something like that. Where to store the "leftovers" depends on the structure of your data/what you're trying to do, so I'll leave that decision up to you.